# How to subtract time when there is a date change in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
    start_date        start_time        end_time
    2018-01-01        23:55:00          00:05:00
    2018-01-02        00:05:00          00:10:00
    2018-01-03        23:59:00          00:05:00
```

I want to calculate the time difference. But, for 1st and 3rd observation, there is a date change in `end_time`.

***How can I do it in pandas?***

Currently, I am using the logic where `end_time` is less than `start_time` I am creating one more column called `end_date` where it increments the `start_date` by 1 and then subtracts the time.

***Is there any other way to do it?***

Comment: Is it possible that the end_time's day is more than one day after the start_date ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution working with timedeltas - if difference are [`days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) equal `-1` then add one day:

```
df['start_time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['start_time'])
df['end_time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['end_time'])

d =  df['end_time'] - df['start_time']
df['diff'] = d.mask(d.dt.days == -1, d + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d'))
print (df)
   start_date start_time end_time     diff
0  2018-01-01   23:55:00 00:05:00 00:10:00
1  2018-01-02   00:05:00 00:10:00 00:05:00
2  2018-01-03   23:59:00 00:05:00 00:06:00
```

Another solution:

```
s = df['end_time'] - df['start_time']
df['diff'] = np.where(df['end_time'] < df['start_time'], 
                      s + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d'), 
                      s)
print (df)

   start_date start_time end_time     diff
0  2018-01-01   23:55:00 00:05:00 00:10:00
1  2018-01-02   00:05:00 00:10:00 00:05:00
2  2018-01-03   23:59:00 00:05:00 00:06:00
```